# How to import data from PostgreSQL to Hadoop?

Tags: postgresql, hadoop, gson

I'm just a beginner in Hadoop and one of my colleges asked me for help in migrating some of PostgreSQL tables to Hadoop. Since I don't have much experience with PostgreSQL (I know databases though), I am not sure what would be the best way for this migration to happen. One of my ideas was to export the tables as gson data and then to process them from the Hadoop, as in this example: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/757934/Apache-Hadoop-for-Windows-Platform. Are there better ways to import data (tables & databases) from PostgreSQL to Hadoop?

Comment: can you share the command to import , I have tried https://www.toptal.com/database/hdfs-tutorial-data-migration-from-postgresql link ,but I am getting error .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sqoop (http://sqoop.apache.org/) is a tool precisely made for this. Go through the documentation, sqoop provides the best and the easiest way to transfer your data.

Comment: what exactly you mean by windows ?...is your Postgre Sql installed on a windows machine ? ..........in general sqoop runs on the side where you hadoop cluster is there since it runs a map reduce job to pull data from db and then dumps it to HDFS.

Comment: Yes, it is on windows machine, and I am running hadoop also on windows

Comment: then you should be able to run it..i am not really sure of what the exact syntax would be but this can be done

Answer (score 1):

Use the below command. It is working for me.

sqoop import --driver=org.postgresql.Driver --connect jdbc:postgresql://localhost/your_db --username you_user --password your_password --table employees --target-dir /sqoop_data -m 1